# Perl URI class wrongly parse user info | Importance of strict and warnings in perl

Tags: perl, uri, cpan

```
use URI;
my $url = new URI("ssh://username@host/path/to/file.txt");
print "User: ", $url->user, "\n";
print "Host: ", $url->host, "\n";
print "Path: ", $url->path, "\n";

output>>>
    User:
    Host: username
    Path: /path/to/file.txt

 expected output>>>
    User: username
    Host: host
    Path: /path/to/file.txt
```

Another example

```
use URI; 
my $url = new URI("ssh://username@host/path/to/file.txt");
print $url->as_string;

output>>>
ssh://username/path/to/file.txt
```

This clearly a bug right? But no one seems to be bothered at all! No one reported this bug in https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=URI. I tried to report one but getting bitcard account sucks.

What are you using in your case? Simple regex?

What I am using?

- Perl version: v5.10.1
- URI version : 1.37

Comment: Your code works for me when I escape the `@` or use single quotes.

Comment: Note that you can report bugs for Perl and core modules (which URI is not) without making an account with RT by using the [`perlbug` utility](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug.html) that is shipped with Perl.

Comment: @simbabque And you can submit tickets for non-core modules by sending an email to `bug-<distribution-name>@rt.cpan.org`, e.g. `bug-URI@rt.cpan.org`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**URI is fine.**

This is a very good example for why you should always `use strict` and `use warnings`.

```
use URI;
my $url = new URI("ssh://username@host/path/to/file.txt");
print $url->user, $url->host, $url->path;

__END__
username/path/to/file.txt
```

Now with `strict`.

```
use strict;
use URI;
my $url = new URI("ssh://username@host/path/to/file.txt");
print $url->user, $url->host, $url->path;

__END__
Global symbol "@host" requires explicit package name at /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl line 1739.
Execution of /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

And now with `use warnings` on top.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI;
my $url = new URI("ssh://username@host/path/to/file.txt");
print $url->user, $url->host, $url->path;

__END__
Possible unintended interpolation of @host in string at /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl line 1740.
Global symbol "@host" requires explicit package name at /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl line 1740.
Execution of /home/simbabque/code/scratch.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

It's pretty clear what is wrong here. Perl thinks `@host` is a variable because you have it in double quotes `""`.

> Possible unintended interpolation of @host in string

Either escape it using `"user\@host"` or use single quotes `''` like `'user@host'`.

Comment: Thanks I just realized after posting the question and laughing out loud...

Answer (score 9):

Here's a good example of why you should ALWAYS `use strict;` `use warnings;`:

> Possible unintended interpolation of @host in string

That means - you're not actually sending what you think you're sending. Try `print`ing it and you'll get:

```
ssh://username/path/to/file.txt
```

Which isn't what you think you're sending.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use URI;

my $url = URI->new("ssh://username\@host/path/to/file.txt");
print "User: ", $url->user, "\n";
print "Host: ", $url->host, "\n";
print "Path: ", $url->path, "\n";
```

However, does give the desired output.

Note - I've changed the `new` line, because `new URI` is indirect object notation, and `URI->new` is better style.

Comment: And then we end up writing almost the same thing :D

Comment: @simbabque: I don;t think it's appropriate to discuss voting or acceptance in comments, or to imply that *faster is better*.

Comment: @Samiron: I suggest that you leave your question open for a day or so to see if anyone has a better answer. The choice is up to you, and speed of response should have no factor. The idea is that you are recommending a solution to other people whose searches bring them to this page.

Comment: @Borodin that was a joke. I think with over 3k rep the OP will get it. :)

Comment: This is good. **Sobrique** and **simbabque** should take their time to add to their answers to produce something even better for the community. Both answers will ultimately be very useful.

Comment: @simbabque: The important thing is whether the OP gets it. I clearly didn't.

Comment: Thanks for constructive comments guys. @Borodin it was a fun moment for me when I realized my own mistake and at the same time saw two similar answer here. But I got a good lesson.